# NGINX with EC certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl

I tried to shift my internal PKI from RSA to EC. So, I generated a test key and certificate using the `brainpoolP384r1` curve. The certificate apparently is fine in general since the following works as expected:

```
root@server:~# openssl s_server -key /etc/nginx/server.example.com.key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 4430 -www -curves brainpoolP384r1
user@client:~$ openssl s_client -connect server.example.com:4430 -curves brainpoolP384r1 -CAfile cacert.pem
```

These connect nicely and the certificate is verified OK. However, with `nginx` the handshake fails with `SSL alert number 40`, which maps to `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP` both using `s_client` or the browser. This is the SSL configuration of `nginx`:

```
# SSL stuff
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/server.example.com.bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/server.example.com.key.pem;
# doesn't work with or without that setting
# ssl_ecdh_curve          brainpoolP384r1;
```

And `/etc/nginx/server.example.com.bundle.crt` is `cat cert.pem cacert.pem > /etc/nginx/server.example.com.bundle.crt`. I know that `ssl_ecdh_curve` is not quite the same as the curve in the certificate, but I gave it a desperate try, since I could not find any equivalent of `-curves` in the `nginx` configuration. It however neither works with or without the `ssl_ecdh_curve` setting.

If I replace the key and certificate by RSA everything works fine.

I guess that I am missing something or is `nginx` not yet ready for EC certificates?

Comment: **Brainpool is deprecated (for TLS).** OpenSSL 1.1.0 (2016) and up by default enable only the 3 NIST curves (P-256, P-384, P-521) and 2 Bernstein (25519 and 448, the latter only implemented in 1.1.1 up), two years before RFC8422 made this official. But for 1.2 and below, the server enabled list only controls _client auth_; the _server_ cert AND ephemeral key are both controlled by extension 10 (formerly 'elliptic_curves' now 'supported_groups') from the _client_ -- what client(s) are you using with this nginx, and with what config or options if applicable? ...

Comment: ... Did you try `openssl s_client` with `-curves` (and suitable `-CAfile/-CApath/-CAstore` if needed)? Note you won't ever get a TLS1.3 connection using Brainpool with any client -- it's prohibited by 8446. OTOH if you use one of the now-standard 5 curves you should 'just work' with pretty much everything. (Note non-TLS-specific functions like `ecparam genpkey pkeyutl req` etc still support Brainpool curves, which are still at least potentially allowed for other applications like CMS/SMIME and timestamping.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a post [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/setting-ssl-ecdh-curve-to-secp384r1-does-not-work/244901/8) which covers the topic very well

The setting is
`ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1:prime256v1;`

Comment: Thank you. Interesting post indeed. I also found https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11548, which gives additional insights However, since I use brainpoolP384r1, I'd not expect secp384r1:prime256v1 to work, and it doesn't. I also tried auto, with no success; but the auto setting doesn't break the RSA certificate handshake at least, which the brainpoolP384r1 setting shown above does.